# How to address filtering in related models in django haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, elasticsearch-2.0

I have the following models:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    topic = CharField(max_length=20)

class Referral(models.Model):
    recipient = ForeignKey(User, related_name=referral_rcvd)
    giver = ForeignKey(User, related_name=referral_given)
    about = CharField(max_length=20)
```

and the following in `search_indexes.py`:

```
class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    topic = indexes.CharField(model_attr='topic')
```

What I want to see in my template is:

```
Search for: <topic>

Results:
<ul>
<topic> <topic.user.username> <topic.user.referral_rcvd.filter(about=topic)
</ul>
```

Working in shell so it's easier, this gives me what I want:

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet as SQS
from models import *
s = SQS().models(Note).auto_query('topic_name')
[i.object.user.referral_rcvd.filter(about=i.object.topic).count() for i in s.all()]
```

But this doesn't work in the html template:

```
{% for result in object_list %}
   {{ result.object.user.referral_rcvd.filter(about=i.object.topic).count() }}
{% endfor %}
```

If it works in the shell, how do I make it work in the template? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it! What I did was to use the `prepare_FOO` method:

```
class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    topic = indexes.CharField(model_attr='topic')
    referral_count = indexes.IntegerField()

    def prepare_referral_count(self, obj):
        topic_name = Note.objects.get(pk=obj.pk).topic
        return obj.user.referral_rcvd.filter(about=topic_name).count()
```

Then I ran `python manage.py update_index` and placed the following in my template:

```
{% for result in object_list %}
   {{ result.referral }}
{% endfor %}
```

It's not `result.object.referral` since we're referring to something in the index.